# How to inject a list of objects that implements a certain generic interface in StructureMap?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface IResult
{}

public interface IDataFetcher<T> where T : IResult
{
   T Fetch();
}
```

In my handler I want to inject al the services that implement `IDataFetcher<T>`:

```
public class MyHandler
{
    public MyHandler(IEnumerable<IDataFetcher<IResult>> fetchers)
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I'm currently registering the `IDataFetchers` as follows:

```
public MyRegistry()
{
    Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.Assembly("name_of_assembly_containg_all_the_classes");
        scan.AddAllTypesOf<IResult>();
        scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IDataFetchers<>));
    });
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in the constructor of `MyHandler` the `fetchers` variable is empty (not null)

What do I need to do to fix this? To make sure fetchers is filled with implementations of `IDataFetcher`?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of trying and googling, I found the answer. I did everyhting right, except for one thing: make `IDataFetcher` covariant:

```
public interface IDataFetcher<out T> where T : IResult
{}
```

Which makes perfectly sense because I use concrete types in the generic types:

```
public class SomeClass : IResult
{
}

public class ConcreteFetcher : IDataFetcher<SomeClass>
{
    public SomeClass Fetch()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Cheers!